# Engagement Time from GA4 using BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I've been trying to get average engaged time for specific pages in BigQuery. But the number I'm getting is radically different from what I see in GA4.  I know there might be differences but this is 5 times less number than in GA4.

Please see screenshots below:

[GA4 UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z5gF.png)
[BigQuery output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOfW5.png)

In GA4 I see the times that seem realistic to me, as those two pages are article with about 1-2 min reading time. However when using BigQuery I see times about 20s. (just to clarify, in BQ output there is no homepage)

After digging I discovered that Average Engagement Time in GA4 UI is actually total engagement time on the specific page divided by number of active users. Using Exploration report in GA4 and Spreatsheet export I've been able to get exact number as it is in GA4 UI. But it seems I can't get it in BigQuery.

Anybody managed to get Engagement Time for the page in BigQuery? I suspect there is an error in the SQL query but after hours of investigating I can't figure it out.

I'm also attaching the part of the query I'm using for this:

```
engagement_time AS (
    SELECT 
        page_location.value.string_value AS page_location,
        user_pseudo_id,
        SUM(engagement_time_msec.value.int_value) AS total_engagement_time_msec
    FROM
        `XXXXXX`,
        UNNEST(event_params) AS page_location,
        UNNEST(event_params) AS engagement_time_msec
    WHERE
        event_name = 'user_engagement'
        AND engagement_time_msec.key = 'engagement_time_msec'
        AND page_location.key = 'page_location'
        AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(event_params) e WHERE e.key = 'page_post_type' AND e.value.string_value = 'post')
        AND event_date = '20230926'
    GROUP BY
        page_location,
        user_pseudo_id
)

SELECT
    p.page_location AS article_url,
    COUNT(DISTINCT p.user_pseudo_id) AS unique_user_count,
    COALESCE(SAFE_DIVIDE(SUM(e.total_engagement_time_msec), COUNT(DISTINCT p.user_pseudo_id)) / 1000, 0) AS avg_engagement_time_seconds_per_user
FROM
    pageviews p
LEFT JOIN
    engagement_time e
ON
    p.page_location = e.page_location AND p.user_pseudo_id = e.user_pseudo_id
GROUP BY
    article_url
ORDER BY
    unique_user_count DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

I'll appreciate any hints. Thanks

Also I tried different query with joining only based on page locations - that returned crazily high times.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is because you are not excluding unengaged sessions (which do not have engagement time) in your formula. If you add a engaged session filter to your where statement it should fix your issue.

```
 unnest(event_params) where key = 'session_engaged') = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain with a scenario.
Lets assume that a user has performed the *scroll* and *view_items_list* actions in sequence on a page before navigating to a new page. Parameter ***user_engagement_msec*** captures duration for each of these events. When the user navigates to a different page, event-name called ***user_engagement*** fires capturing the remaining time before navigating to the next page.

Remove event_name = 'user_engagement' in the where clause and that fixes the issue.